# Filter rows by other rows with shared columns in KQL

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I have a table with 3 columns

| Group | Type | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Short | 1 |
| A | Short | 2 |
| A | Long | 3 |
| A | Short | 4 |
| B | Short | 1 |
| ... |  |  |

I want to query and group extract all the rows of that group, but exclude rows with same type and that the index-1 is also exists. For example, if I query Group1, I want to get:

| Group | Type | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Short | 1 |
| A | Long | 3 |
| A | Short | 4 |

Here we removed the Type1 Index 2 since index 1 already exists with same type.

I tried this query:

```
traces
| where Group == "A"
| expend OutterType = Type
| where (Index-1) !in((
    traces
    | where Group == "A" and OutterType == Type
    | project Index))
```

But it says that `OutterType` doesn't exist in the context of the inner query.

How can filter those rows?

Comment: Correlated queries are not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let t = datatable(Group:string, Type:string, Index:int)
[
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,1
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,2
   ,"A" ,"Long"  ,3
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,4
   ,"B" ,"Short" ,1
];
t
| join kind=leftanti (t | extend Index = Index + 1) on Group, Type, Index
```

| Group | Type | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | Short | 1 |
| A | Short | 1 |
| A | Short | 4 |
| A | Long | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBVSEksAcKknFQN96L80gKr4pKizLx0HYWQyoJUOMczLyW1wiozr0STlyual0tBQUFHyVEJSARn5BeVABmG2ASNkAV98vPSlYA8Y2wqTaCCTmhmxlrzcpXwctUoZOVn5ilkZ+al2OakppUk5pVkKmiUKNQopFaUpOalQNwH9AyE1lYw1FTIz1MAewjiE6gXAGocjAr1AAAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(Group:string, Type:string, Index:int)
[
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,1
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,2
   ,"A" ,"Long"  ,3
   ,"A" ,"Short" ,4
   ,"B" ,"Short" ,1
]
| extend GroupType = strcat(Group, ":", Type)
| partition by GroupType
  (
      project-away GroupType
    | order by Index asc
    | where Index - 1 != prev(Index) 
  )
```

| Group | Type | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Long | 3 |
| B | Short | 1 |
| A | Short | 1 |
| A | Short | 4 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22PPwvCMBDF90K/wzNTC+1QdSo46CKCm27ikLZHrUhS0tNW8MOb1L+UJhByv3t3966QbG92oWBt9LVOGzaVKiPs7zV9g40qqEsrxaHvHXwPQCSWwj67kzZsP8kYnP7DrValsNFsTDl/w9Wg59H3HqCOSRXo7TlXWMD6yiW/HEcQqXj5DZ28loYrrrRCdv8VuQFBP8We2ugz5RzLVg4kwAPaFGRccb81ZJN/Mu2JDL1xjASThW1Ft6AnIZwsfAKtnBXYUAEAAA==)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It seems to be working on Fiddle, but when I try it in my actual table (App Insights) it throws a compile error: `The name 'hint.strategy' is not a recognized parameter for this operator.`

Comment: Services based on Azure Data Explorer (Application Insights, Log Analytics, Resource Graph etc.) do not expose the entire KQL capabilities. Please tag your post properly. This answer will work without the hint (I'll remove it now), using the legacy strategy, which is limited 64 partitions.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. I will tag them properly next time

Comment: I added the tagging. For the benefit of future viewers :-)